# How to install vim?

Tags: vim-latex

I am trying to install vim LaTeX suite but on the website there isn't specifically any files I can find for mac so I am confused. Where do I go to download it.

I currently run OS X 10.12.6 if that matters.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok so I downloaded the contents into my computer and then in the home directory I did 
mkdir .vim
to make a new directory, but when I did ls in the home directory I could not find the folder.

Comment: I should be same for any linux/unix right?

Comment: Oh ok, can anyone else answer? I went to that link and went to the linked post linked in the link given in the post. I went and downloaded macvim, does this suffice or do I need to do more?

Comment: Well, does it work? Doesn't that tell you whether it suffices or not? Are you sure you didn't have `vim` to begin with? OS X used to have it out-of-the-box, as far as I remember, so you only needed to install the plugin or whatever.

Comment: Its just a text editor, I thought I would be able to compile the latex. I dont know if it is supposed to compile it.

Comment: Yes I believe that is the situation, I'm not sure how to install the plugin.

Comment: I am using the solution tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112698/how-to-install-vim-latex here, but I'm not sure how to get .vimrc...Am I supposed to create that directory somewhere?...
EDIT: I found a file named vimrc in the root, but I was unable to get access to edit it

Comment: @user279540: `.vimrc` is your local config file. Under Linux and Unix it can be created in your home directory, i.e. `~/.vimrc`. Under Windows it should be in the home directory as well, maybe as `_vimrc`. No idea about Mac. You could try just to use `~/.vimrc` inside vim, e.g. `w ~/.vimrc` to write the current content to it.

Comment: @user279540 on Mac it should be `.vimrc` I guess (literally guess). After you did `mkdir .vim` you didn't find it using `ls` because `ls` doesn't show files beginning with a dot. Use `ls -a` to also see all files in the current directory which start with a dot.